# How can i make the array show one at a time with a delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> each div shows up as a block and I want them 
>   to start showing when the page is ready

```
<div id="blocks">


</div>
```

enter code here

```
var mainArray = new Array();

mainArray[0] = "<div class='tile'> </div>"
mainArray[1] = "<div class='tile'> </div>"
mainArray[2] = "<div class='tile'> </div>"
         //adds to #blocks
for (var i = 0; i < mainArray[i].length; i++) {
$('#blocks').append(mainArray[i])
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using setTimeout()

```
var mainArray = new Array();

mainArray[0] = "<div class='tile'>1</div>"
mainArray[1] = "<div class='tile'>2</div>"
mainArray[2] = "<div class='tile'>3</div>"
//adds to #blocks
for (var i = 0; i < mainArray.length; i++) {
    (function(idx){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(mainArray[idx]).hide().appendTo('#blocks').fadeIn()
        }, idx * 2000)
    })(i)
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qurJE/)

Comment: Thank you so much! where would i put an animation like fadeIn or slideDown ?